# Grouped results with SQL Server Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, grouping

Is it possible to generate results as shown in the attachment using SQL server 2008 Stored Procedures?

[image]

Comment: you mean when you execute the sp, the grid result should show that? if you want to show that in your client app, better to do the 'graphical' grouping there.

Comment: Thats right. Is it possible to see the results like that with SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can user a SELECT to have what you showed:

```
SELECT vendor,
       category,
       sub_category,
       product,
       price,
       vendor_name
  FROM (
SELECT          vendor AS ID,
                NULL AS vendor,
                category,
                sub_category,
                product,
                price,
                vendor_name
  FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT vendor AS ID,
                vendor,
                NULL AS category,
                NULL AS sub_category,
                NULL AS product,
                NULL AS price,
                NULL AS vendor_name
  FROM table
) T
ORDER BY ID, category
```